# Deleting $1$'s from a $(0,1)$-matrix

Tags: matrices

Suppose you have a $(0,1)$-matrix $A$ and $A$ has $m$ rows and $m^2$ columns. Each column has exactly three $1$'s. How many rows should we delete to make sure that each column has strictly less than three $1$'s?

I appreciate any help/hint.

Comment: what is a (0,1)-matrix?

Comment: The elements of matrix are either 1 or 0.

Comment: You want a function of the matrix or a general lower bound or something else? There isn't one constant answer for all matrices.

Comment: Do we get to pick the rows after we've seen A?

Comment: "Should" implies an optimization of some type, but your question doesn't specify it.  Are we trying to choose the least possible number of rows that accomplishes the criterion?  Are we choosing just the number of rows to delete, but the selection of rows is at random (akin to "how many socks should we draw in order to have a matching pair")?  As two others have commented, do we choose them based on $A$ or does it have to work regardless of $A$?

Comment: @ Artimis Fowl, Erick Wong: I'm looking for an upper bound for the number of rows I have to delete to make sure no columns have three $1$'s. For example, I would like to say If I remove $m/2$ of rows, then all columns have less than $(<)$ $1$'s.

Comment: @ConMan: Yes! $A$ is given to you.

Comment: If you leave three rows undeleted, one of the columns might have its $1$'s in those three rows.  So to be sure of having less than three $1$'s in each column, you'd need to delete at least $m-2$ rows.

Comment: @RobertIsrael that's a bound, but probably not a tight one. You'd need every triple of rows to share ones on some column, but there are $O(m^3)$ triples, and they would have to be distinct. This line of reasoning probably gives a tighter answer.

Comment: You wrote "I would like to say If I remove $m/2$ of rows, then all columns have less than ..."  That's apparently not what you meant.  You wanted to say "there is some set of at most $m/2$ rows (depending on $A$) that ..."

Comment: @RobertIsrael yeah, you're righ.

Answer (score 4):

At the start we have $m$ rows, and $a_0 = m^2$ columns with three ones.
At stage $k$ (after $k$ rows have been deleted), there will be $a_k$ columns that still have three ones.  Thus the remaining $m-k$ rows have an average of $\dfrac{3 a_k}{m-k}$ ones.  At least one of them has at least that many ones: if we delete it, 
we'll have $$a_{k+1} \le a_k - \frac{3 a_k}{m-k} = \frac{m-k-3}{m-k} a_k $$
Thus $$a_k \le m^2 \prod_{j=0}^{k-1} \frac{m-j-3}{m-j} = m^2 \frac{(m-3)!(m-k)!}{(m-k-3)! m!}  = \frac{m(m-k)(m-k-1)(m-k-2)}{(m-1)(m-2)}$$
When the right side $< 1$, we are done.  Setting the right side to $1$ gives us a cubic polynomial to solve for $k$.  The solution in radicals will be messy, but it's not too bad to find the asymptotics.  I get

$$ k \sim m - m^{1/3} - 1 + o(1/m)$$

and in fact $k = \lceil m - m^{1/3} - 1 \rceil$ should always work.

Comment: A nitpick, but the average number of ones would probably be bigger than the above, as $a_k$ ignores rows that have already lost their ones. However you want to ignore these for your algorithm anyway. Perhaps "ones that matter"?